# PyQt6: Find element by path in QTreewidget

Tags: python, search, pyqt6, qtreewidget

How to select this element in Qtreewidget using the path to an element?

The path is written as an example string: **parent/parent/parent/parent/element**

It is important to search for elements along the entire path and not only by the name of this element, because there may be many elements in the tree with the same name, but each one will certainly have a different path.

I tried to solve it in ten ways:

```
def find_and_select_item(self):
    path = self.comboBox_Scene.currentText()
    path_elements = path.split('/')
    current_item = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
    for element in path_elements:
        items = self.treeWidget.findItems(element, Qt.MatchFlag, 0)
        if items:
            current_item = items[0]
        else:
            # Element not found in the current level of the tree
            return None

    # Select the found item
    current_item.setSelected(True)
    return current_item
```

Unfortunately, this function returns an error::
`TypeError: findItems(self, text: str, flags: Qt.MatchFlag, column: int = 0): argument 2 has unexpected type 'EnumType'`

Comment: Typo: Change to `Qt.MatchFlag.MatchExactly`

Comment: This is not acceptable, and results may be inaccurate or invalid, because `findItems` always search for a *single* part in the *whole* model, without considering the context of parent items. Most importantly, it will fail for paths containing repeated parts (eg. `A/B/A`). The *only* way to properly navigate though the view is by doing a recursive search that considers context and item level, which of will be easier to achieve through the view's `model()`.

Comment: @musicamante Unfortunately, I cannot solve this problem on my own. In my application, I use many elements from QT, and I haven't had any issues with any of them except Qtreewidget. The easiest solution would be to give up on using this element in this version, but I don't want to do that because it's beneficial for the overall functionality of the application. Besides, I don't like giving up. I am reading the QT documentation to solve my problem, but unfortunately, it's not clear to me. Could you somehow guide me so that I can make progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most easily implemented using recursion, which can provide a more general solution that is capable of finding multiple matching pathways in the tree (if necessary).

Below is a basic working demo that shows how to achieve this. Since the question states that each element has a *different path*, this demo only looks for the *first matching item*. However, the `searchByPath` method returns a generator that can iterate over *all* matches if necessary (and it can also start searching from any point in the tree).

[image]

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        for text in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'):
            level0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree, [text])
            for text in ('Cyan', 'Violet', 'Yellow'):
                level1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(level0, [text])
                for text in ('Orange', 'Brown', 'Purple'):
                    level2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(level1, [text])
                    for text in ('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'):
                        level3 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(level2, [text])
        self.edit.setText('Green/Violet/Orange/Bronze')

    def handleButton(self):
        self.tree.clearSelection()
        self.tree.collapseAll()
        path = self.edit.text()
        if path:
            item = next(self.searchByPath(path), None)
            if item is not None:
                self.tree.scrollToItem(item)
                item.setSelected(True)

    def searchByPath(self, path, root=None):
        if root is None:
            root = self.tree.invisibleRootItem()
        elements = list(map(str.strip, path.split('/')))
        last = len(elements) - 1
        def search(parent, level=0):
            if level <= last:
                target = elements[level]
                for index in range(parent.childCount()):
                    child = parent.child(index)
                    if child.text(0) != target:
                        continue
                    if level == last:
                        yield child
                    else:
                        yield from search(child, level + 1)
        return search(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Great educational example. It works perfectly :) I implemented this solution into my code, and I have one problem. After returning from the searchByPath function, the item is None. I have no idea why. I checked the code step by step, and it seems that everything is working, but in the end, the item is None.

Comment: @Marcin It should return `None` if the path doesn't exist in the tree. Are you absolutely certain that you are using the correct path? Note that my solution is *case-sensitive* and strips whitespace. I can't really diagnose the problem any further without seeing your actual code. Can you edit your answer and provide a [mre]? Or perhaps give a link to the source code for your prroject?

Comment: My mistake, all because of one little space in the source path :D :D
**child.text(0).replace(' ','')** and all OK ;-)
The solution works perfectly!

Comment: How co verticali center "scrollToItem"? I Try use **self.treeWidget.scrollToItem(item, hint = 3)** but this modifikactin return error `TypeError: scrollToItem(self, item: Optional[QTreeWidgetItem], hint: QAbstractItemView.ScrollHint = QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible): argument 'hint' has unexpected type 'int'`I was looking for a solution to this problem in [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollHint-enum]

Comment: solving centering problems self.treeWidget.scrollToItem is:  self.treeWidget.scrollToItem is: `self.treeWidget.scrollToItem(item, QAbstractItemView.ScrollHint.PositionAtCenter)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve it in new ways:

```
def iterator_treewiget(self, widget, content):
    for i in range(widget.childCount()):
        item = widget.child(i)
        text = item.text(0)

        if content in text:
            self.treeWidget.setCurrentItem(item)
            return
        self.iterator_treewiget(item, content)

def find_and_select_item(self):
    content = self.comboBox_Scene.currentText()
    items = content.split('/')
    n = len(items)
    item = items[n-1]
    if content:
        root = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
        self.iterator_treewiget(root, item)
```

I found a solution to my problem, but it has some drawbacks. Firstly, it hangs when there are two elements that are the same but in different locations.
For example:

```
parent/parent/parent/parent/element
parent1/parent1/element
paren2/parent2/parent2/element1
parent/parent/parent/parent/element2
parent1/parent1/element3
paren2/parent2/parent2/element4
parent/parent/parent/parent/element5
parent1/parent1/element6
paren2/parent2/parent2/element7
parent/parent/parent/parent/element8
parent1/parent1/element9
paren2/parent2/parent2/element10
```

When I point to "element1", "element2", "element3"... 4,5,6,7,8,9,10, everything works. When I select one of the "element", the program hangs.
Secondly, with a larger database of elements after several different element selections, the error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Answer (score -1):

In PyQt6, the usage of enumerations might be slightly different from PyQt5.
In PyQt6, Qt.MatchFlag might be replaced with a specific enumeration, such as Qt.MatchFlag.MatchExactly.

Here’s an updated version of your function:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QDir, Qt  # Make sure to include the specific Qt modules you need

def find_and_select_item(self):
    path = self.comboBox_Scene.currentText()
    path_elements = path.split('/')
    current_item = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
    
    for element in path_elements:
        items = self.treeWidget.findItems(element, Qt.MatchFlag.MatchExactly, 0)
        if items:
            current_item = items[0]
        else:
            # Element not found in the current level of the tree
            return None

    # Select the found item
    current_item.setSelected(True)
    return current_item
```

Approch 2:

It seems that the issue may be related to the differences in PyQt6 or how the findItems method is being used. ensuring that the element you are searching for matches exactly and is case-sensitive:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

def find_and_select_item(self):
    path = self.comboBox_Scene.currentText()
    path_elements = path.split('/')
    current_item = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()

    for element in path_elements:
        items = self.treeWidget.findItems(element, Qt.MatchExactly | Qt.MatchCaseSensitive, 0)
        if items:
            current_item = items[0]
            print("Found item:", current_item.text(0))  # Print the text content of the found item
            # Move the current_item reference to the found item
            current_item = items[0]
        else:
            print(f"Element '{element}' not found in the current level of the tree.")
            return None

    # Select the last found item
    current_item.setSelected(True)
    print("Selected item:", current_item.text(0))  # Print the text content of the selected item
    return current_item
```

Comment: TypeError: findItems(self, text: str, flags: Qt.MatchFlag, column: int = 0): argument 2 has unexpected type 'EnumType'

Comment: @Marcin, Code updated. Please make sure you import Qt correctly and use the appropriate match flag

Comment: Ensure that you import Qt from PyQt5.QtCore or use the full path to Qt.MatchFlag.

Comment: i have this line:  **from PyQt6.QtCore import QDir, Qt**

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I'm using PyQT version 6?

Comment: @Marcin please try updated code for PyQT version 6

Comment: I now use last version PyQT v. 6.6.1 Ok, now it doesn't return an error but the function doesn't work. Does not select any item from the tree

Comment: Try approach 2 now and let me know if same issue persist.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'MatchExactly'

Comment: Ahhh… approach 2 Updated. Please use Qt.MatchExactly instead of Qt.MatchFlag.MatchExactly.

Comment: I've already tried to do it this way. No, the function does not return an error but still does not select an item in the tree

Comment: The printed variables look like this: `current_item: <PyQt6.QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem object at 0x1072c2170> items[0]: <PyQt6.QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem object at 0x1072c1fc0>` They will never be the same. Maybe that's the problem here?

Comment: @Marcin , To investigate the issue further, you might want to print some additional information, such as the text content of these items or their parent-child relationships. Updated Approach 2 with print statements, please check

Comment: If the path looks like this: `patent/parent1/parent2/element` Found item: prints only `parent`. Selected item: prints nothing.

Comment: Please check updated code:I moved the assignment of current_item inside the loop after finding the items. This ensures that the current_item reference is correctly updated to the found item, allowing the loop to continue searching through the hierarchy.

Test this modification and see if it resolves the issue you are facing with printing only the parent and not reaching the last element in the path.

Comment: The path looks like this: `GRAFIKA/SPORT/PILKA_NOZNA/TVP_PILKA_NOZNA/SCENES/3013_PLANSZA_MECZU`  Print elements: `Found item: GRAFIKA`
`Found item: SPORT` `Element 'PILKA_NOZNA' not found in the current level of the tree.` "Selected item:" not printing